# Logistic Regression - Calculate how much each attribute contributed to final probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, logistic-regression

I am trying to calculate how much each attribute of an observation has contributed to the final probability given by logistic regression. I have trained pythons sklearn logistic regression on my data set. Now I am using it to make predictions on a live data set. I would like to know how much each attribute (X) contributes to the final prediction given by sklearns predict_proba method.

Here is the formula for calculating the probabilities by the logreg.

ln p/(1-p)=α+ β^T X

p; probability of being 1
α; bias
β^T; coefficients transposed
X; attribute values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Binary logistic regression

Assuming binary logistic regression it is pretty easy; you have weights for each feature of your input which, after training, increases or decreases probability.

Let's say you have `4` features and output either `0` or `1`. Let's assume that after training, coefficients for those features are, respectively:

```
[0.0, -2.2, 1.3, -0.45]
```

Here, you can easily see that 2nd (numbering from `0`) feature with weight `1.3` contributes to higher probability if this input feature for specific example is greater than zero (or, in other words, feature `2` is positively correlated with probability).

On the other hand, first feature (`-2.2`) is negatively correlated with probability, while the zeroth feature no matter it's value has no effect on probability outcome.

You can get those coefficients/weights by issuing

```
clf.coeffs_
```

provided your `LogisticRegression` is named `clf`.

## Multinomial logistic regression

In general, multinomial logistic regression would have a matrix of features, each row for probability of a label.

Once again, let's assume you want to classify input into one of `5` classes and `34` input features and let's assume learned weight matrix looks like this:

```
[
    [0.1, 2.2, -0.1, 0.133], # Features of class 0
    [-2, -1.1, 0, 4.56],
    [-0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.4],
    [3.3, -2, 15, -9.4],
    [0.45, 0.5, 0.66, 5.5],
]
```

Now you could apply the same ideas as seen above; let's take how each of those `4` features contribute to probability of outputing label `3`, so we take this row:

```
[3.3, -2, 15, -9.4]
```

And you can see feature `0` and `2` have positive correlation with probability of outputting label `3`, while features `1` and `3` have negative.

## Bias

Bias contributes prior knowledge. Assume all weights are zero. In binary case, there is only one bias, so it would either output small (negative bias) probability or large (positive bias).

In multinomial case there is one bias for each class but it works similarly.

## Contribution of coefficients

You could normalize weights into `[-1, 1]` range, with the biggest negative weight having biggest impact on outputing zero probability and highest positive having the biggest impact on outputing probability of one.

Comment: Hi @szymon-maszke thanks for the answer. Makes sense. Let's say the logistic regression gives a probability of the class being a 1 and it is 0.8.
I would like to know how much of that 0.8 was contributed by each of the features. So that the numbers add up to 0.8. I understand I would use the coefficients. But simply multiplying them with the values won't give that answer.

Comment: @DominikŽulovecSajovic  You would have to take this specific example and multiply by weights to see which feature contributed how to overall probability. If you were to add bias after that and sum everything up, you would get a logit (unnormalized probability). Applying sigmoid on that value would give you this `0.8` probability.